# parse difficult date/time string in excel table formula

Tags: excel, datetime, parsing

I have date/time text values in a column of an excel table. Ignore the quotation marks...

```
"October 1, 2020 6:00 pm"
"October 2, 2020 6:00 am"
```

Excel does not parse this automatically as a date/time.

What formula will allow me to parse this to a date/time excel represents as a true date/time

Cheers

Comment: In the source column, how is it formatted, Text or Actual Date Time?

Answer (score 2):

If above information is in string format and consistent as depicted then below formula can be used.

For date:

`=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)-3))`

For time:

`=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)-2,99))`

---

If data is in actual date time then following can be used.

For date:

`=INT(A1)`

Format cell in date format.

For time:

`=A1-INT(A1)`

Format cell in time format.

---

**Edit:**

You can try below formula which is rather unwieldy. It should work irrespective of locale.

`=DATE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),2*99,99))+0,LOOKUP(99,SEARCH(TEXT(1+ROW($A$1:$A$12)*29,"mmmm"),A1,1),ROW($A$1:$A$12)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),",",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))+0)`

Comment: Yes the data is just a string. The time value formula seems to work, but the DATEVALUE does not work. I get this error: "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"

Comment: @johowie Could you check the formula through Formula Evaluation option and see at what step it is failing? Or alternatively, post sample data where it is failing for you. Also can you advise your locale settings please?

Comment: @TomSharpe I had not considered the locale impact while posting the formula. What error do you get?

Comment: #Value! - A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type.

Comment: The evaluation (of the datevalue formula) works fine until it gets to datevalue(October 1, 2020)

Comment: @TomSharpe please check the longish formula I have posted now.

Comment: @johowie Please test the longish formula posted in the edit and advise if that helps.